# SSIS package is skipping a DFT while executing

Tags: ssis-2012

`SSIS Package` finished successfully but it has skipped a `DFT` in which I am trying to transfer a data from one table to another in the database . Though the data is there in the source table , it is not fetching the records to the `Dest`. table

Please note that

1. DFT  is not  disabled
2. I am using Logical AND in the connector and all the previous tasks to it  are executing successfully fetching the data
3. The eventhandlers handled to that DFT , Pre execute and post execute are also getting executed . I have one more step after that DFT , even that is getting executed.
4. Please highly note that this is working fine in my Local . I am facing this issue when I deploy the same ETL pacakge to the server .

Please Help me whether I have to check any Other settings

Thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: did u tried with Dataviewer ? can u also try to execute with File system instead of DB which could identify possible error

Comment: already tried with Dataviewer . Will try to execute with File system . Thanks anyway :)